# PHP White Page Controller Issue

Tags: php, sql, oop, codeigniter

I have a section of my code that is causing my whole page to load white with no error message.

I have debuged my code and the following section is causing my issue but I cannot work out why:

**Problem Code:**

```
        if($this->image_model->updatePage($id, $caption)) {
                        $data['title'] = 'Image Captions';
                        $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
                        $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
                        $data['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
                        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/imagecaption', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"
                        $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data); #Loads the given template and passes the $data['content'] into it    

                        }//END if updatePage
```

**Full Controller Document:**

```
function index(){

    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))redirect('admin/home');

        $data['title'] = 'Image Captions';
        $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
        $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
        $data['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/imagecaption', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"
        $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data); #Loads the given template and passes the $data['content'] into it

    if ($this->input->post('submit')){

                #The User has submitted updates, lets begin!

                #Set The validation Rules   
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('captionInput', 'Caption', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

                    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){ #Form Validation Fails Load The Default Page

                    $data['title'] = 'Image Captions';
                    $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
                    $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
                    $data['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
                    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/imagecaption', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"
                    $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data); #Loads the given template and passes the $data['content'] into it

                }// END Form Validation 

                #Form Validation passed, so lets continue updating.
                #lets set some variables to pass into the database for editing.

                    $caption = $this->input->post('captionInput', TRUE);
                    $this->db->escape($caption); # Lets check for security and mel objects :)

                #Now if imageCaption fails to update the database then show "there was a problem".

                    if($this->image_model->updatePage($id, $caption)) {
                        $data['title'] = 'Image Captions';
                        $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
                        $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
                        $data['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
                        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/imagecaption', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"
                        $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data); #Loads the given template and passes the $data['content'] into it    

                        }//END if updatePage
                    }else{
                        $data['title'] = 'Image Captions';
                        $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
                        $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
                        $data['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
                        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/imagecaption', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"
                        $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data); #Loads the given template and passes the $data['content'] into it

    } //END Submit 

} //END function index()

}
```

**Image Model:**

```
class Image_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
}

function getImages($path = NULL) {
foreach($this->db->get('images')->result_array() as $r) {

    $rows[] = $r;
}

return $rows;
}

function addImage($imgdata) {
    $this->db->insert('images',$imgdata);
    return;
}

function deleteimage($id){

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $q = $this->db->get('images');
    $row = $q->row_array();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0){
        //delete from the database
        $this->db->where('id', $id); 
        $this->db->delete('images');

        //lets delete the image
        unlink("includes/uploads/gallery/".$row['imagename']);
        //lets delete the thumb.
        unlink("includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/".$row['thumbname']);
    }//END if num_rows
}//END function deleteImage($id)

function updateCaption($id = NULL, $caption = NULL){
    #set the $data passed to the function into an array, content being the column name.
    $data = array('description' => $caption);

    $this ->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('images', $data);

    return TRUE;
}

}//END class Image_model
```

Comment: there's no error, as you have error checking off, turn on and display errors.

Comment: They are on by default when using CI

Comment: if your using CL then how can you have a 'white page' ??

Comment: when that white screen happens, turn the logging threshold to 4 and debug your heart out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller is `$this->image_model` an instance of your `Image_Model` class?  If so, in the model you posted, there does not appear to be an `updatePage()` method .

Comment: A few words have just been said :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it has nothing to do with this:

```
} //END function index()

}
```

Have you confirmed that you're not suppressing errors? What do your error logs say?

Comment: Allen,  The 2x }} One ends the index function and one ends the class.  I have checked my install of CI and its in development.  My error log is not showing anything

Comment: Are you sure you're not suppressing errors ANYWHERE in ANY of those functions with @ ? Grep your application folder for @.

Comment: Nope all fine could not find them

Answer (score 0):

In your controller document, where you have this block of code towards the end, remove the extra **}** that you have before the **else** keyword

```
if($this->image_model->updatePage($id, $caption)) {
                    $data['title'] = 'Image Captions';
                    $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
                    $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
                    $data['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
                    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/imagecaption', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"
                    $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data); #Loads the given template and passes the $data['content'] into it    

                    }/*END if updatePage*/
                }else{
                    $data['title'] = 'Image Captions';
                    $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
                    $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
                    $data['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
                    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/imagecaption', $data, TRUE);   #Loads the "content"
                    $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data); #Loads the given template and passes the $data['content'] into it 
                }
```

Comment: I have done the following:  }//END if updatePage
       else{ Still not working